# cassandra cluster ping loss

Tags: cassandra, ping, cassandra-3.0, loss

We have 3 nodes Cassandra cluster. 2 nodes are in EU (seeds) and 1 node is in US. Sometimes we have network problems - **ping loss between nodes in EU and US**. Effect after network problems is that some data is missing on US node. We need to start manually `nodetool repair` to repair loss. Is there anyone who could advice me how to deal in this case?

Here is our keyspace creation:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '2', 'dc2': '1'}  AND durable_writes = false;
```

`dc1` - EU servers - 2 nodes

`dc2` - US Server - 1 node

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved similar problem by automating cassandra repair.

We run a cron job from a cassandra operations machine (a machine which is not part of the cluster, but from which we can run nodetool commands directed to the cluster under consideration).

The cron job runs nodetool repair every midnight. It runs incremental repair everyday, except on 1st of every month when it runs full repair. You can decide schedule based on your needs.

I don't see any other solution. What you can do when the nodes are facing the most basic problem - ping loss.

What else you can do is reconsider the decision to have multi-region cluster. Try considering having multi-zone ( nodes located on different physical location but within a region) cluster.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

I read more about this problem and analyzed our scenario. It seems that missing data is from tables where parameter ```gc_grace_seconds = 60```. In other tables where ```gc_grace_seconds``` is 12 hours we do not have missing data.

Do you think if we increase ```gc_grace_seconds``` to 12 hours will solve our problem?

Comment: "Expired data continues to be available for read requests during the grace period, see gc_grace_seconds." What I don't know is that whether expired data is replicated or not. If not then the data loss would be more prominent for data with larger gc_grace_seconds on a particular node. But before getting into it, you should try to narrow down the problem. Is it network problem or something else.?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that our problem is in `gc_grace_seconds` . Our tables are created as follow:

`default_time_to_live = 7200
 gc_grace_seconds = 60`

It seems that if USA nodes are DOWN, after `gc_grace_seconds` period data could not be synchronized. We tried to increase value of `gc_grace_seconds` up to 7200 and seems that when USA nodes are UP data is in sync.